# php div content including html to variable

Tags: javascript, php

So i have this script that should convert anything including HTML inside the pdf div to pdf.

My script is as follows:

```
<div id="pdf">To Pdf</div>
<div id="not_to_pdf">Not to Pdf</div>

<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="PDF"></form>

<?php if ($_POST['submit']) {
require_once("pdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first 
$pdf = "value of div!";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdf);


 $mpdf->Output('x.pdf', 'D'); 

} ?>
```

I tried doing some javascript and using DOMDOCUMENT but I dont understand why it should be that hard. I realy want to display the text inside the div pdf tag and be able to capture it as a variable. How would I go over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
<div id="not_to_pdf">Not to Pdf</div>
<div id="pdf">To Pdf</div> 

<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="content" id="content" type="hidden"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PDF" onclick="document.getElementById('content').value=document.getElementById('not_to_pdf').innerHTML">
</form>

<?php if ($_POST['submit']) {
require_once("pdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first 
$pdf = "value of div!";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($_POST['content']);


 $mpdf->Output('x.pdf', 'D'); 

} ?>
```

Comment: thanks this works! I still wonder how I can do the getelementbyID thing in PHP with something like domdocument without loading some external page ...